# Difference between `groupby.unique` and `groupby.first` functions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to combine two neighborhood names with the same postal code in a dataframe.

Initially I used `groupby.unique()` function but it returns a `ndarray` in each cell. I later tried `groupby.first()` function which returns the value of the repeated postal code.

```
PCode =pd.DataFrame({'PostalCode':['M4A','M5A','M5A'],'Borough':['North York','Downtown Toronto','Downtown Toronto'],'Neighbourhood':['Victoria Village','Harbourfront','Regent Park']})
PCode.groupby('PostalCode')['PostalCode'].unique()
PCode.groupby('PostalCode')['PostalCode'].first()
```

I wonder whether there is a way to extract the postal code out of the returned `ndarray` for the `groupby.unique()` function to produce exactly the same result as when using the `groupby.first()` function.

Comment: Please show your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder there is a way to extract the postal code out of the returned ndarray

Use `str[0]`:

```
print(PCode.groupby('PostalCode')['PostalCode'].unique().str[0])

PostalCode
M4A    M4A
M5A    M5A
```